# Part of second capture group in Regular Expression

Tags: regex

How to determine the first part (before point) of the second capture group?

Ik have a string like this : `aabb_cc.dd_eeff`
To split this string in groups, I use the regex `(.*)_(.*)_(.*)`
I will now only use the part before the dot (cc) of the second group (cc.dd)? The dot is optional. How can I accomplish this?

I try this without success: `(.*)_(.*(?=\.))_(.*)`

The result have to be:

```
Group 1 : aabb
Group 2 : cc
Group 3 : eeff
```

Comment: Try [`this regex`](https://regex101.com/r/nCutU9/1)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee That regex only contains 2 capturing groups, while OP wanted 3.

Comment: @connectyourcharger I have updated my regex - [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/nCutU9/2)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee, With dot okay, but without no match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Since the `.` is optional, use this:

`(.*)_(.*?)(?:\..*)?_(.*) /g`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HqMjS7/3)

---

Use this:

`(.*)_(.*)\..*_(.*)`

Just capture what is needed.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HqMjS7/2)

Comment: With dot (aabb_cc.dd_eeff) it's working fine, but without a dot (aabb_ccdd_eeff) no match

Comment: Hi CinCout, this is working (.*)_(.*?)(?:\..*)?_(.*)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you tried does not match because this part `.*(?=\.)` will match until looking at the last dot.

If you want a full match, you have to also match the dot itself and match what comes after the dot.

```
(.*)_(.*(?=\.))\.[^_]+_(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/za0e0V/3)

You could optimize the pattern using a negated character class to capture matching not a dot or an underscore. You could change the `.*` to use a negated character class `[^_]+` to prevent unnecessary backtracking.

Updated to account for the optional dot:

```
([^_\s]+)_([^._\s]+)(?:\.[^._\s]+)?_([^_\s]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cXXw8w/1)

Comment: This is almost what I want. I only want 3 Groups. In your demo Group 1, 3 and 4. is that possible?

Comment: @Raymond I have updated the pattern to have 3 capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to use lazy quantifiers `?`, and just match all characters, a `.`, then more characters. Note the lack of `?` in the last group because you want to match all characters non-optionally.

```
(.*?)_(.*?)\..*?_(.*)
```

Comment: With dot (aabb_cc.dd_eeff) it's working fine, but without a dot (aabb_ccdd_eeff) no match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(.*?)_(.*?)\..*?_(.*)
```

Notice what the second pair of parentheses encloses, and what it doesn't. I used a lazy `*?` to find the first `.`, put that all in the group, then outside the group, match the rest until `_`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LpWlUq/1)